# Using Overloaded Strings

Tags: haskell, language-extension, ghcjs, overloaded-strings

`OverloadedStrings` extension is really very useful, however it has some downsides.
Consider the following function definition:

```
someFunction :: ToJSSTring a => a -> IO ()
someFunction = js_function . toJSSTring
```

In this case when if I want to pass a literal value I have to add a type signature explicitly when `OverloadedStrings` is enabled:

```
someFunction ("This is plain string" :: String)
someFunction ("And this one is Text" :: Data.Text.Text)
```

The reason for this necessity is quite obvious, I suppose `OverloadedStrings` was designed to ease the passing of literal values to functions that have strict type signatures, making the developer free from writing `pack`s everywhere where a `Text` value is needed.

The question is there any way, say, to default all string literals without type signatures to `Text`, or `String`? Or should I just split my code to general functions (with the `ToJSString` type constraint) and arbitrary ones, which have strict type signatures for their arguments?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can turn on `ExtendedDefaultRules` as well (https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/random-code-snippets/overloadedstrings-defaults):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
import Data.Text (Text, pack)

newtype JSString = JSString Text
    deriving Show

class ToJSString a where
    toJSString :: a -> JSString
instance ToJSString [Char] where
    toJSString = toJSString . pack
instance ToJSString Text where
    toJSString = JSString

someFunction :: ToJSString a => a -> IO ()
someFunction = print . toJSString

main :: IO ()
main = someFunction "Hello World"
```

**EDIT** You may also want to add `default (Text)` to the top of your module to have it use `Text` instead of `String` by default.

Comment: You never ceases to amaze me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI link is broken