# Haskell using OverloadedStrings, but getting [Char] error anyway

Tags: haskell, generics, overloaded-strings

I understand from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894987/couldnt-match-expected-type-text-with-actual-type-char) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366802/error-couldnt-match-expected-type-char-with-actual-type-char) that using the `PRAGMA OverloadedStrings` means I should be able to use Text as my string-type.

However, as I test out [my data types](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) with Text, I get the following error:

```
$ stack ghci
Prelude> :l myfile.hs
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> Rec "asd" "m"

<interactive>:46:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘Rec’, namely ‘"asd"’
      In the expression: Rec "asd" "m"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = Rec "asd" "m"

<interactive>:46:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the second argument of ‘Rec’, namely ‘"m"’
      In the expression: Rec "asd" "m"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = Rec "asd" "m"
```

My code is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric,  OverloadedStrings,  DefaultSignatures,  TypeOperators,  FlexibleContexts, RecordWildCards, FlexibleInstances, ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set
-- import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text (Text)
import GHC.Generics

data Rec  = Rec {
     recCategory :: Text,
     recId :: Text
     } deriving Generic
```

What am I doing wrong?

I see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778415/using-overloaded-strings) a suggestion to:

> EDIT You may also want to add default (Text) to the top of your module
>   to have it use Text instead of String by default.

But it's not clear to me what the syntax would be that allows this default

Comment: re. syntax for adding `default (Text)`: just add a line that reads exactly so after your `import` list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have enabled ˋOverloadedStringsˋ in your file, but that doesn’t enable it in ghci as well. You’d need ˋ:set -XOverloadedStringsˋ for that. Note that the extension affects places where you write string literals, it doesn’t matter whether or not it was enabled where you defined your data type.

Comment: Huh.  Is there a syntax that would ask my ghci session to match the pragma requested on the module I'm loading?  I'm trying to load a lot of pragma as I work on this file--it seems like it would be easy to miss something in `:set -XOverloadedStrings -XDeriveGeneric" etc., and kind of cumbersome to type up given it's already in the file.

Comment: @Mittenchops not as far as I’m aware, and I don’t think it’d be as useful as you’re imagining, because many language extensions aren’t needed at use side (and in this case it’s unneeded in your definition). You can set s number of default extensions to turn on though, depending on how exactly you start ghci.

Comment: Add your favorites to `~/.ghci`